# oracle replace view during query

Tags: oracle

What happens if a view is replaced while a query that uses that view is running?
I guess that since a view is just a stored query, nothing will happen. When running a query that includes a view, the view is replaced by the actual query. Is that assumption correct?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SQL cursor is open Oracle fetches all data from rollback segment. So even you drop table in another session your first session will continue to fetch rows from dropped table. Same for view.

Comment: This is generally not true.  Dropping the table, or even truncating it, changes the DATA_OBJECT_ID.  In many cases you will get lucky, and Oracle has *some* of the data "pre-fetched" somewhere and can continue to deliver rows.  Mixing DDL and SELECTs are bound to cause problems at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* currently-running queries will continue to run even if their underlying views are modified.

Do not confuse Data Definition Language (DDL) changes with the Oracle mantra "readers and writers do not block each other".  The technology that prevents that blocking does *not* prevent DDL from interfering with queries.  There most certainly are cases where a DDL statement can break a currently-running SQL statement.

The examples below demonstrate a `TRUNCATE` breaking a `SELECT`, and then demonstrate a similar `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` not breaking a `SELECT`.

**Truncate interfering with currently-running query**

```
--Session #1 - Create table and data.
drop table table1;
create table table1(a number);
insert into table1 select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;

--Session #2 - Query table.  Use an IDE and only retrieve the first N rows.
select * from table1;

--Session #1 - Truncate table.
truncate table table1;

--Session #2: Retrieve the rest of the rows.
--This may be difficult to reproduce, and may depend on memory
--or other environment settings.

ORA-08103: object no longer exists
```

**View change does not interfere with currently-running query**

```
--Session #1 - Create table and data.
drop table table1;
create table table1(a number);
insert into table1 select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
create or replace view view1 as select a from table1;

--Session #2 - Query table.  Use an IDE and only retrieve the first N rows.
select * from view1;

--Session #1 - Create a new version of the view.
create or replace view view1 as select 1 a from table1;

--Session #2: Retrieve the rest of the rows.
All rows are returned with the original values.
```

**Warnings**

This is only a simple example, do not take this as proof that a `SELECT` is always immune to view changes.  I'm not sure if you could ever prove that view changes don't interfere with `SELECT`.  Your assumption that a view is initially replaced by the query makes sense but I'm not 100% sure it is accurate.  Oracle has mechanisms to re-optimize queries in the middle of an execution, it's possible that one of those re-optimizations
 can break something.

If you need to be certain this will work, here are some options:

1. Contact Oracle Support.
2. Offer a bounty for a counter-example.  That still won't prove it's impossible but it certainly will increase your confidence.
3. Thoroughly test your application.